# Macro to insert the time in the last line

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to put the right time in the last row of column H but when I launch the macro, it updates the time in the other rows of the same column as well, is there a way to avoid this? Thank you

```
Sub orologio()
  Dim y As Integer
  Dim LastRowF As Long
  Worksheets(4).Activate
  Sheets(4).Unprotect
  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
  With ActiveSheet
    LastRowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
  End With
  For y = 2 To LastRowF
    If Range("E" & y) Like "*" Then
      Range(Cells(y, "H"), Cells(y, "H")).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
      Range(Cells(y, "h"), Cells(y, "H")) = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm")
  End If
Next y
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if this is your desired outcome.

```
Sub orologio()
  Dim y As Integer
  Dim LastRowF As Long
  
  Worksheets(4).Activate
  Sheets(4).Unprotect

  With ActiveSheet
    LastRowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Removed the FOR-NEXT because you said you only to update the last row.
    If .Range("E" & LastRowF) Like "*" Then      
        .Range(Cells(LastRowF, "H")).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        .Range(Cells(LastRowF, "H")) = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm")
    End If

  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @John22, where do you want to put the current date/time, is it on last row only? or on the whole column H with condition that column E has value? Please clarify what are on columns E, G & H.

Comment: Hi, looked more calmly, I didn't notice my mistake, everything works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only in the last row of H:H, please use the next code. No need of activation, selection or iteration:

```
Sub orologio()
  Dim y As Integer, sh4 As Worksheet, LastRowG As Long
  
  Set sh4 = Worksheets(4)
  sh4.Unprotect

  LastRowG = sh4.cells(sh4.rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).row

  With .Range("H" & LastRowG)
       .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
       .value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy hh:mm")
  End With
End Sub
```